# the iocb struct used in Fio and linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, benchmarking

I am studying request issuing peocess in FIO. I think FIO call `io_u_submit(td, io_u)` to submit io. And in `io_u_submit(td, io_u)`, the system function `io_submit(ld->aio_ctx, nr, iocbs)` is called to enque `iocbs`. However, the `iocb` structure used in FIO is defined in /usr/include/libaio.h:

```
struct iocb {
    PADDEDptr(void *data, __pad1);  /* Return in the io completion event */
    /* key: For use in identifying io requests */
    /* aio_rw_flags: RWF_* flags (such as RWF_NOWAIT) */
    PADDED(unsigned key, aio_rw_flags);

    short       aio_lio_opcode; 
    short       aio_reqprio;
    int     aio_fildes;
#ifdef NotePid
    pid_t   aio_pid; // i added it
#endif 
    union {
        struct io_iocb_common       c;
        struct io_iocb_vector       v;
        struct io_iocb_poll     poll;
        struct io_iocb_sockaddr saddr;
    } u;
};
```

which is different from the `iocb` struct required by `io_submit(io_context_t ctx, long nr, struct iocb *ios[])` that is defined in /usr/include/linux/aio_abi.h:

```
struct iocb {
    /* these are internal to the kernel/libc. */
    __u64   aio_data;   /* data to be returned in event's data */

#if defined(__BYTE_ORDER) ? __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN : defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    __u32   aio_key;    /* the kernel sets aio_key to the req # */
    __kernel_rwf_t aio_rw_flags;    /* RWF_* flags */
#elif defined(__BYTE_ORDER) ? __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN : defined(__BIG_ENDIAN)
    __kernel_rwf_t aio_rw_flags;    /* RWF_* flags */
    __u32   aio_key;    /* the kernel sets aio_key to the req # */
#else
#error edit for your odd byteorder.
#endif

    /* common fields */
    __u16   aio_lio_opcode; /* see IOCB_CMD_ above */
    __s16   aio_reqprio;
    __u32   aio_fildes;

    __u64   aio_buf;
    __u64   aio_nbytes;
    __s64   aio_offset;

    /* extra parameters */
    __u64   aio_reserved2;  /* TODO: use this for a (struct sigevent *) */

    /* flags for the "struct iocb" */
    __u32   aio_flags;

    /*
     * if the IOCB_FLAG_RESFD flag of "aio_flags" is set, this is an
     * eventfd to signal AIO readiness to
     */
    __u32   aio_resfd;
}; /* 64 bytes */
```

I don't understand how could this work. How can the iocbs in FIO passed down to io_submit() successfully since these two struc are different?

I want to add new parameter in iocb and pass it to the request finally enqueued to denote which job in FIO issued this requets. My original idea was: recording the pid in iocb struc, passing the iocb to io_submit(), them copy the pid from iocb to the req. but later i found the problem mentioned above.